# Git branch from remote tag

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I've created a new local git repository mirrored from another remote repository:

```
git init
git remote add original {url}
git pull original master
git remote add origin {url}
git push -u origin master
```

This would create a mirror of `original`s master branch.
Now I would like to create a new branch of a tag from `original`.

How the commands should look like?
I tried `git checkout -b newbranch original/tagname` but I got:

```
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'newbranch' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'original/tagname' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to wrap this in two instructions

```
git checkout tagname && git checkout -b newbranch
```

Alternatively

```
git checkout tagname -b newbranch
```

Comment: It is a remote tag, both commands didn't work (same error message as described above)

Comment: You should do `git pull original tagname`

Comment: @dtrunk try adding the tags/ prefix to your remote tag name like this 

`git checkout tags/<remote-tag-name> -b <new-local-branch-name>`

Comment: And how to I track a remote tag? And can I pull from it?

Comment: Need to do a fetch forst to update the tag list

Comment: To clarify, before one can use `git checkout <tag-name> -b <new-branch-name>` one must first do a `git fetch --tags` so that the local repo has knowledge of the existing tags.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me

```
$git fetch --tags
$git tag
$git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <tagname>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no concept of “remote tracking tags” like there are “remote tracking branches”. You either get the tags from the repo or you don’t. At least in the standard settings. You can change that, but I would not recommend that. Does this not work?

```
git checkout -b newbranch tagname
```

Comment: do `git fetch origin -t` and try again.

Answer (score -2):

The following bash script can be used for automating this process:

```
#!/bin/bash

old_name="old-branch-name"
new_name="new-branch-name"

git checkout ${old_name}
git branch -m ${old_name} ${new_name}
git push origin :${old_name} ${new_name}
git push origin -u ${new_name}
echo "Branch ${old_name} renamed to ${new_name}"
```