# Git branch from a remote branch tag

Tags: git, github, version-control, tags, branching-and-merging

Here is my setup

1. Remote named `upstream` points to the the branch where tag exists.
2. Remote named `origin` points to my fork.

I want to create a branch under `origin` that is even with the `upstream tag`. Make some changes to this newly created branch and raise a pull request to the upstream.

I am currently checked out on a branch under `origin`.

Performed the following operations based on this answer : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043450/git-branch-from-remote-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043450/git-branch-from-remote-taga)

`git fetch upstream <TAG_NAME>`

1.

`git checkout <TAG_NAME> -b <NEW_BRANCH>`

`fatal: '<TAG_NAME>' is not a commit and a branch '<NEW_BRANCH>' cannot be created from it`

2.

`git checkout tags/<TAG_NAME> -b <NEW_BRANCH>`

`fatal: 'tags/<TAG_NAME>' is not a commit and a branch '<NEW_BRANCH>' cannot be created from it`

3.

`git checkout upstream <TAG_NAME> -b <NEW_BRANCH>`

`fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch '<NEW_BRANCH>' at the same time.`

Comment: It looks like your fetch didn't get the tag you're trying to fetch. Did you get an error message from it? Now, when you do `git tag -l`, is the tag listed? Maybe try a global `git fetch upstream` to get all the refs from there, and see if the tag shows up.

Comment: Presumably, when you say that "upstream points to the branch where tag exists", you mean it points to the remote, not the branch, right? It's not relevant what branch that tag might exist on, it's got its own independent existence of any branches, since a tag is just a pointer to a specific commit.

Comment: "remote tag" isn't a thing, in Git. *Remote* is a thing and *tag* is a thing; tags are names in a repository, and you can only use the ones that are *in* **your** repository, but you can use `git fetch` to a *remote* to obtain commits and names from that remote. The important part here is actually the commit, not the tag, but `git fetch --tags upstream` will try to take each of their tag names in their repository and create an identical tag name in your repository. This could fail because you could already have a tag spelled that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the new [`git switch` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4601643/6309) instead

```
git switch -c newBranch tagName
```

This assumes that `git tag -l` does list the tag you want after a `git fetch --tags upstream`.